# What does "for row in cur.execute ("sql query")" return?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

`for row in cur.execute("select business_id,count(text) from reviews group by business_id"):`

What type of variables does this return? Is the `row` a tuple or a list?
How do I use the `row` element in order to turn it into a string and slice it into smaller strings?

Comment: Firstly, why don't you try it and see? And secondly, tuples and lists are completely equivalent in terms of accessing elements.

Comment: Try it and see!  A simple way to display the type of a variable is `print(type(row))`, although if you just `print(row)` it shows `( )` if it is a tuple and `[ ]` if it is a list.  You can create a string from a list or a tuple using `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a tuple. According to the MySQL Connector documentation for [cursor.fetchone()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html):

> This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, or None if no more rows are available. By default, the **returned tuple** consists of data returned by the MySQL server, converted to Python objects.
>   ...
>   The fetchone() method is used by fetchall() and fetchmany(). **It is also used when a cursor is used as an iterator.**

You can then access the columns by indexing.

```
for row in cur.execute("select business_id,count(text) from reviews group by business_id"):
    id = row[0]
    count = row[1]
    # Use id and count here
```

Comment: So I need to turn it into a string via `str(row)` in order to deal with it?

Comment: @Zap I don't see why you would do that. Just use `row[0]` to get the business ID, and `row[1]` to get the count.